# ReactJS + Redux: How can I choose an image from my local drive and upload it?

Tags: javascript, redux, reactjs

In ReactJS + Redux, I have a button and once clicked, I want my local drive, Photos directory to open up, and want to be able to choose an image file, and upload it onto . Looked around and can't seem to find the right answer.

Is there such a way to do so?

Comment: Try using the Javascript File API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: @goldage5 I tried it but for `<input ....>` I am getting an error: `Unterminated JSX contents`. Am I missing something?

Comment: That error means you have an unclosed tag somewhere in your JSX. If you post the code I can help you debug it.